Looking for Short and better way to create widget in Tkinter
I am using Python 3.11.9 in windows 11 OS (home edition)
I create text entry using three lines shown in code below:
import tkinter as tk
class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, title:str="Bill generation", x:int=0, y:int=0, **kwargs):
            tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        
            self.default_txt_for_desc=tk.StringVar()
            self.default_txt_for_desc.set("PCS")
            self.txt_desc=tk.Entry(self,width=10,textvariable=self.default_txt_for_desc)
            self.txt_desc.grid(column=0,row=0)
            self.update_idletasks()
            self.state('zoomed')
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
            Application(title="Bill printing app").mainloop()

How can I do that in one line?

What's the goal with doing it on one line? I would argue it's a best practice to separate the creation of a widget from laying it out on the screen.

You can compress this code into this line:
(self.txt_desc := tk.Entry(self, width=10, textvariable=(self.default_txt_for_desc := tk.StringVar()).set("PCS") and None or self.default_txt_for_desc).grid(row=0, column=0)

This creates the Entry self.txt_desc and the StringVar self.default_txt_for_desc. It uses the walrus operator := to assign the variables. This allows multiple assignments and further operations on the objects.
Although this is short (in the sense if the amount of lines), it is not readable and much worse than your version. A short way is not necessarily better. The line can easily lead to confusion later on.
The PEP 8 guidelines for example require you to have a maximum line length of 79 characters. This limit should allow the code to be read on most computer displays without horizontal scrolling.
Instead of collecting sections in one line, you can make use of functions and modules for such pieces, to organise your code.
Also note that having more code in one line will not perform necessarily any better in terms of speed. Even if there is a performance advantage, it is overshadowed by readability.

Can you give an example of 'you can make use of functions and modules for such pieces, to organise your code.' with regard to my code about creating entry widget ? so that readability is not lost . Thanks.

I believe your code is quite organised, but if you want, you can wrap the related lines un a method like def create_desc_entry(self) -> None: ... and call it within your init. Or you can create a function dedicated to creating all of your widgets to separate this logic from your init. Readability just means that it is easy to understand what your code and parts of it do... But it is your code, so do whatever you feel like is the easiest to understand. Happy coding!

i believe in my current code all widget creation is happening in init . Is it possible to write a function with argument (1)text or label or button and (2) default text and it will return widget of corresponding type . Function for entry widget creation will return its text variable which we will use in other places to modify its text . In both cases we will give parent frame of widget and its row and col grid position as arguments also .

Thanks oskar . Moderators have closed the question .
